# Copy the latest version of an SQL script within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working with a number of different datasets and Docker. For example, I have a number of files in a folder called /databases like model_1.sql, model_2.sql, model_3.sql etc. I would like my Dockerfile to be configured so that when I copy a file over from my databases folder, it picks out only the most recent file (e.x. model_3.sql) while ignoring the others. Is this possible?

edit: since my question apparently wasn't clear enough, here is the pertinent line -

```
# Copy our newest version 
COPY database/model_3.sql /
```

Rather than manually typing the 3, I would like to be able to do something along the lines of model_*.sql but not copy all of them, copy the the most recent. So if I eventually add a model_4.sql, I will not need to update my Dockerfile when I run it, it will automatically add model_4 instead of model_3.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Okay, mind elaborating?

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. And make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve the same using the `--build-args` option.
Example: `Dockerfile`

```
FROM image:tag
ARG LATEST_FILE #Here I'll parse the LATEST_FILE info as a build argument.

COPY ${LATEST_FILE} #And the value for LATEST_FILE is replaced here.
```

Docker build command:

```
docker build -f myDockerfile --build-arg LATEST_FILE=$(ls -t database/model_*.sql | head -1) -t imagename:tag .
```

`$(ls -t database/model_*.sql | head -1)` will get you the latest file and will be copied in the `COPY` step.

Please be aware that parsing `ls` is only dangerous when the files name contains spaces or some funny characters. If you guarantee that the filenames will not have such characters, then parsing `ls` is ok.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I can't test now but I will tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!